# ADF business components through RMI vs EJB and Toplink

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, oracle-adf

What would the differences be in implementing remote business logic?

Currently we are planning on using [ADF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Application_Development_Framework) to develop front-end web applications (moving from [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts)). What are the differences between the front end calling [EJBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean) using [TopLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TopLink) vs ADF Business Components through [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) in terms of scalability as the migration from Struts to ADF will also encompass PL/SQL and Oracle Forms, thus increasing the user count drastically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADF is pretty broad, as it encompasses front end all the way down through data access.  It's a great [RAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development) framework if you are going to use the entire stack, but isn't so hot if you are only going to use one portion or the other.

I am assuming you are talking about using either TopLink or ADF business components (BC4J) for the data access layer.

I would say that if you are planning on using an RMI based application, that TopLink would probably be better, mainly because the power of BC4J is in its view objects, which don't serialize (hence translating those results into TopLink style value objects, anyway).

If you are doing a straight up and down web application and don't really care about EJBs and RMI then I think you'll find that BC4J offers a lot in the way of making standard web applications scale... Long story short, it maps SQL into view objects, which are basically smart datagrids that have very tunable behavior, which can be bound directly to [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) components of the Oracle ADF Faces, giving really good seamless RAD.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going through a similar situation right now. I'm am not an expert, but here what I've gathered from my experience. Whether EJB's using Toplink or ADF scales better depends quite a bit on the particulars of your situation. In some cases one might be better than the other, but I get the feeling that they are both pretty good solutions.

However since you mention that the project also involves the migration of Oracle Forms, then it seems that ADF would be the best choice since Oracle seems to be positioning JDeveloper and ADF as the successor for Forms and Reports (see the [ADF Documentation targeting Forms and Designer Developers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/collateral/4gl/formsdesignerj2ee.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the EJB deployment of ADF BC. It needs a lot of RMI synchronisation. I used it with ADF [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29). Going to the next record takes about three seconds. We need to rewrite the comboboxes to make it perform.

In [Oracle 11g](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#History) (2009-05 edition) you will get the option to create an SDO WS based on a viewobject and you can use these in ADF BC serviced based entities in a other ADF project.